# Conflicting 'order' models in application 'order'

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have a problem with overwitten model from Django oscar. I want add a new field to model but when i do it i have **RuntimeError: Conflicting 'order' models in application 'order':  and .**

Thats my code 
**myapp.oscar_apps.order.models.py**

```
from oscar.apps.order.models import *  # noqa
from oscar.apps.order.abstract_models import AbstractOrder  # noqa
from django.db import models

class Order(AbstractOrder):
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)


from oscar.apps.order.models import *
```

*myapp.oscar_apps.order.**init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'bakdrop.oscar_apps.order.config.OrderConfig'
```

*myapp.oscar_apps.order.config.py

```
from myapp.apps.order import config


class OrderConfig(config.OrderConfig):
    name = 'myapp.oscar_apps.order'
```

Can anybody help my solve this problem ?

Update my INSTALLED_APPS

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'compressor',
    'paypal',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_select2',
    'myapp.apps.user',
    'myapp.apps.organization',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'djcelery',

] + get_core_apps([
                'myapp.apps.promotions',
                'myapp.oscar_apps.checkout',
                'myapp.oscar_apps.order',
                'myapp.oscar_apps.basket',
                'myapp.oscar_apps.shipping',
                'myapp.oscar_apps.payment',

            ])
```

Comment: What does your `INSTALLED_APPS` look like? Have you replaced Oscar's order app with your own, as [in the docs](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/customisation.html#replace-oscar-s-app-with-your-own-in-installed-apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

`from oscar.apps.order.models import *`

I think you need

`from myapp.oscar.apps.order.models import *`

A good debugging strategy for this is to comment out all of these, and reintroduce them line by line. That way you can pin-point the error:

```
get_core_apps([
                'myapp.apps.promotions',
                #'myapp.oscar_apps.checkout',
                #'myapp.oscar_apps.order',
                #'myapp.oscar_apps.basket',
                #'myapp.oscar_apps.shipping',
                #'myapp.oscar_apps.payment',

            ])
```